# Define exe output folder path

Tags: vb.net, directory, exe

I have .exe file which generate .csv file in the same location as .exe file.
when I run my vb.net code .csv file is not generate in .exe file location but in location where my compiled vb.net exe code is runned.

how can I define .exe output csv file folder path?
I use this code in vb.net

```
    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
    psi.FileName = "E:\Downlaoder.exe"
    psi.Verb = "runas"
    Process.Start(psi).WaitForExit()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your program doesn't change the startup directory by itself then you should specify the [WorkingDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) when you define the ProcessStartInfo instance

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
psi.FileName = "E:\Downlaoder.exe"
psi.WorkingDirectory = "E:\"  ' This if you want the file to be created in E root.
```

Comment: it is still not working, files are downloaded to my main .exe directory not in directory where my Downloader.exe exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) and use it as the path to save the file to the exe directory

Comment: Welcome. Consider bringing in an example from the link to illustrate how `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` works. Link only answers are discouraged on SO. By providing an example you're ensuring that your answer can stand on it's own should the link, for whatever reason, die.